# avidemux problems with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, avidemux

I installed 16.04 a few days ago and had to reinstall some apps. One of them was `avidemux`. After I installed it from the Software Center, I couldn't get it to work properly. It wouldn't even load a video clip before giving me an error message and closing.

After trying many commands to purge the `avidemux` files, I still can't get it to reinstall from the Software Center...

Any tips?

Comment: No answers yet, so I thought I would try again. No progress. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I used the PPA :
https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/avidemux1

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/avidemux1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install avidemux
```

Comment: Many error-messages, and in fact  only *Qt4* (to see movies but not edit) is running.

Comment: A problem with `avidemux2.6-jobs`. See apt and 


Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that
You asked for an impossible situation or, if you are using the
Unstable distribution, that some required packages were not
Still created or were removed from the "Incoming".
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have mismatched dependencies:
 Avidemux2.6-qt: Depends: avidemux2.6-jobs but will not install
E: Impossible to fix problems, you kept (hold) broken packages.

Comment: Even after `sudo apt-get -f install`
Reading package lists ... Ready
Building dependency tree
Reading status information ... Ready
0 packages upgraded, 0 new packages installed, 0 to be removed and 11 not upgraded.

Comment: PS:  after `sudo apt install avidemux`  an error about `avidemux-qt`  dependence (and `avidemux-qt`  was not installed).